# How to check a checkbox in Google Apps Script and uncheck all the other cells?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, checkbox

So I'm trying to make a sign-in/sign-up form on Google Sheets, and I have two checkboxes, one that says login, and one with sign up. In my apps script, I'm trying to make it so that only one of them can be checked. This is my code, and it's not working. Help?

```
function signupLogin() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  if (sheet.getRange('A13').isChecked() === 'TRUE') {
    sheet.getRange('B13').setValue('FALSE');
  } else {
    sheet.getRange('B13').setValue('TRUE'); 
  }
}
```

The code will always make the second checkbox ticked, even if the first one is ticked.

Comment: Explain "*it's not working.*"

Comment: @TheMaster The code will always make the second checkbox ticked, even if the first one is ticked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you check `A13` or `B13` the other cell will be unchecked automatically.

Therefore, I think an [onEdit()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) solution is what you are looking for:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  
  const as = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  const cell = e.range.getA1Notation();
  const cell_checks = ['A13','B13'];
  if(as.getName() == "Sheet1" && cell_checks.includes(cell) && e.range.isChecked())
  {cell_checks.filter(val=>val!=cell).forEach(c=>as.getRange(c).uncheck())}  
}
```

To use this solution, just **save** the aforementioned code to the script editor and then every time you click on the checkbox in `Sheet1` (modify the name to your needs) the rest checkboxes will be unchecked.

This code is also scalable. Namely, if you want to have **multiple** checkboxes and when you click one of them, the rest become unchecked. You can define the list of your checkboxes here:

```
 const cell_checks = ['A13','B13'];
```

Comment: I really want to try this, but what do I replace all of the "e"s with? Like in onEdit(e), e.source.getActiveSheet(); e.range.getA1Notation, and e.range.isChecked()). I'm kind of new to Apps Script

Comment: you just **save** this code after you paste it to the script editor. You **don't** need to manually execute it. Then make sure that the checkboxes are in a sheet named **Sheet1** and in cells A13, B13. You can change the latter from the code, it is very straightforward.

Comment: elegant programming technique by the way

Comment: I found this solution and it works.  However, it takes 20-30 seconds for it to work.  My range of check marks is M4:M15.  I have therefor scaled it as suggested:   const cell_checks = ['M4','M5','M6','M7','M8','M9','M10','M11','M12','M13','M14','M15'];.  Do you have any idea why it is so slow to uncheck?

Answer (score 4):

#### Issue:

```
if (sheet.getRange('A13').isChecked() === 'TRUE') {
```

- [Range.isChecked()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#ischecked) returns

  - `true` or `false` of type `Boolean` or
  - `null` of type `null`
- It does NOT return

  - `"TRUE"` of type `String`
- So, the condition will never be satisfied according to [Strict equality comparison rules:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality)

> If the operands are of different types, return false

#### Solution:

- Use strict comparison with literal Boolean `true`

  ```
  if (sheet.getRange('A13').isChecked() === true) {
  ```
- Or if `null` is NOT expected, Use the returned Boolean directly in `if`'s condition:

  ```
  if (sheet.getRange('A13').isChecked()) {
  ```

Comment: good explanation of the issue but he still needs to run the function from the script editor...

Comment: @Marios Hmmm... Yes. It'll  otherwise run oneach edit. Probably not what op wants.

Answer (score 2):

You are literally comparing Boolean result of `sheet.getRange('A13').isChecked()` to the string literal which results in always false expression.
Simply check the boolean:

```
function signupLogin() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  if (sheet.getRange('A13').getValue()) {
    sheet.getRange('B13').setValue('FALSE');
  } else {
    sheet.getRange('B13').setValue('TRUE'); 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To the question **"How to check a checkbox in Google Apps Script?"**:

```js
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  .getSheetByName('sheetName')
  .getRange('D5')
  .check();
```